# How does Visual Studio Team Services Transport Secret Variables?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are currently in the process of evaluating Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) release management as our continuous deployment (CD) tool. My System Administrators are not crazy about storing any kind of password or secret in VSTS or any other CD tool without having a good understanding of what security is being used. I have already found documentation that describes how VSTS stores Secret Variables at rest, but what I can not find is documentation that describes what security VSTS uses to transports Secret Variables to the build/Release Agents. This is important because we will be deploying to on-premises pre-production environments which means the credentials and secrets entered into VSTS will be sent over the internet. So to sum up my question what encryption does VSTS use to communicate with agents.

Documentation on how VSTS secures Secret Variables at rest.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables

Comment: You can find the information here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/team-services-security-whitepaper#intrusion-protection-response. "To ensure data is not intercepted or modified while in transit between you and Team Services, we encrypt via HTTPS / SSL."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all standard HTTPS. No special protocols or encryption are involved.

Comment: do you have a link to any documentation that explains this. Also do you know if the passwords and secrets are decrypted before or after they are sent to the Agent?